# Android app being killed in the background - Best practice to return to login screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

If the app is killed in the background by the system I would like the user to be returned to the first activity in the stack, i.e the login activity.

Currently I do this by checking an application level variable in `onCreate()` of each activity and starting the login activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (wasKilledInBackground()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        super.onCreate(null);
        finish();
        return;
    }
```

This works, but it requires us to add code to each activity because the rest of onCreate() must not be executed (static model classes missing)

On iOS, state restoration can be disabled for the whole application.

I was wondering if there is a) a better way to redirect to login besides touching each activity or b) something comparable to what is available on iOS

Comment: where do you set the application level variable from ?

Comment: Basically we have static data attached to the application class that is filled when the user logs in. If it is not present when the activity is created, we know that the app must have been killed. We can not retain this data so we need to query it again from the server.

Comment: see if you can make use of [app architecture components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html)